# abt naudio input and output devices

Tags: naudio

I am pretty new to Naudio, trying to understand it, 
I require the following to be done in my application

I have couple of devices connected to my system 
say 
1) head set - with a mic 
2) inbuilt system mic and speakers

I require to do the following 
the audio from the two input devices(headset mic and system mic)  should be mixed and a byte array needs to be constructed. how can this be done using naudio

Also, the system speakers and headset would receive a stream that needs to played on both 
any concept ? or classes that i can use ?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the type of headset:

1. If the headset plugs into the sound-card's audio jacks (with a pair of 3.5mm plugs for instance) then you can't target the headset's speakers and microphones as distinct from the system's speakers and microphone.  They are indistinguishable, except in very rare configurations.
2. If the headset is connected via USB then you can use the device enumeration options to select the device to attach to.  In this case you might be able to independently address the different microphones and speakers... try it out and see.